# How to protect myself from unethical business collecting on an invalid past due amount?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, car, consumer-protection, debt-collection

I had my car serviced by a local shop.  I ultimately picked them because they were close and didn't really research their online reputation.  Suffice it to say I was less than pleased.  The car broke down the first day out of the shop.

I returned the car to the shop and asked for the repairs to be made whole.  When I took my car to a different service shop for a second opinion, it was explained to me that the repairs were done incorrectly, parts where missing and installed backwards.  (They even used caulking to stop an oil leak.)

I had the second shop repair the car and the original problem for $1800 USD and I disputed the original $1400 USD with my credit card provider.  Today I found out I won.

I have heard stories of unscrupulous businesses, and I am worried the first shop will send me to collections for $1400.  While I have pictures, written documentation from the second shop and the victory from the credit card dispute, what do I do if a collection agency comes calling?  I clearly don't owe the money according to Visa, but how does the law see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't lose any sleep on it until it actually happens.  I believe generally the agreement of the merchant with the credit card company says they must submit to the company's arbitration.  If they come back to you, I would definitely get in touch with Visa to complain.

**[Here's some great advice on dealing with unscrupulous debt collection](http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2010/07/more-on-debt-collection/59752/)**, the main points being

- it does exist
- don't ignore it; do respond or show up in court
- in most states you can tell them to cease contact
- complain to your state AG, or talk to a consumer advocate lawyer

It's actually you that should be threatening to sue *them* if the repairs were incompetent or dangerous!